# checking the status of sync

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there any way to know what is the status of the sync like: Progress, Complete, Error,etc.

I am looking the information either in the api or the google drive application i install in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not available, if I am guessing correctly what you wan: A way of polling the Drive Client to see its state.

The API and the Sync clients are not related as such.

Comment: Yes, i need to know a way to see if the files completed syncing.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think to do is if it locks files it's syncing, enumerate the files you are trying to get to and monitor their lock status, assuming it's done if there are no locked or new files in 10 seconds.